# IdentityServer3 samples with database conectivity

Tags: identityserver3

I am using ThinkTecture IdentityServer 3 as Token Service. I found so many samples, but all are with InMemory stores https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples. Has anyone published a sample with persistant stores for Clients, Users and Scopes.

I found a few for IdentityServer4  but not for IdentityServer3.

Please share if you found any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [this sample](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Admin.EntityFramework) From Identity Server's GitHub Page to store Client and Scopes in Database. It Also Provides a simple UI to manages Clients and/or Scopes configuration.And [this sample](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/master/source/AspNetIdentity) shows how you can store users and claims.
I put together all these features in one solution, you can see that in [my GitHub Page](https://github.com/MostafaEsmaeili/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/master/source/All%20in%20One%20Example)